# Android GoogleMaps: Zoom in / out animation not working

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm using `GoogleMaps` in my Android App and I want to have that smooth animation when you `zoom out/in` with your fingers. It is working but itimmediately stopd as I lift my fingers from display. Swipe to left and right is working. It will move automatically and then slow down. But zoom in/out animation is not working at all.

Tried to set these parameters to 'true' but without changes:

```
gmap.uiSettings.isZoomGesturesEnabled = true
```

Its weird that it doesnt work (animation). According to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/controls#map_gestures) it should work exactly as original GoogleMaps if you enable `isZoomGesturesEnabled = true`. Every single zoom in/out gesture is working with smooth slow-down animation as expected. Only `Two finger pinch/stretch` doesnt work with animation.

UPDATE:

To better understand my problem:

Here is animation if you swipe in GoogleMap

[image]

Here is animation if you zoom out by gesture (it stops immediately).
I used clean project without any code, just basic GoogleMap activity.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
private static final LatLng SYDNEY = new LatLng(-33.88,151.21);
private static final LatLng MOUNTAIN_VIEW = new LatLng(37.4, -122.1);
private GoogleMap map;


// Move the camera instantly to Sydney with a zoom of 15.
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(SYDNEY, 15));

// Zoom in, animating the camera.
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());

// Zoom out to zoom level 10, animating with a duration of 2 seconds.
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
```

for details follow this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/views

Comment: Doesn't work. As I zoom out by gesture and lift my fingers from display it immediately stops zooming out.